# Command to move a file to a directory even if the directory is not present

Tags: command-line, mv

Is there a way to move file to a new directory without explicitly creating the directory using `mkdir` command and then move the file using `mv`

Comment: the destination directory is single or multiple? I mean for expamle `/home/user/1/2/3` 1 2 3 directorys not exist..

Comment: it is multi level directory. Yes exactly, I want to move file that is in directory 1 to directory 3 which is inside directory 2

Comment: so as a example you want `mv existingfile /home/user/1/2/3` where 1 2 3 does not exist. Seems no way without creating those.. You may have single line command that can do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional method would be

```
mkdir -p
```

will create all elements of the path that do not exist.

You can change it with `&& mv`
Example:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/1/2/3/ && mv /tmp/file /tmp/1/2/3/
```

The /tmp/1/2/3/ can be a variable that you can reuse.

It can also be done with `tar` but then you need to make it with the directory structure already there. Untarring it elsewhere will create the paths that do not exist.

You can also use `rsync`. If the destination does not exist it will create it for you. Example

```
rsync -a --relative /new/dir/1/2/3/ /old/dir/
```

That last one seems to the best method to me. rsync is an amazing tool for transferring files. Local and remote.

Comment: maybe you want to check if the directory still exist. Read man test and you want to use 

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  # Control will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists.
fi
```

Comment: why? both the -p and rsync already take care of that.